# Why does monodroid click event not work?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to make a click event for a ListView in monodroid.

```
public class QuizMenuActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Menu);

        ListView menuList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView_Menu);

        string[] items = new string[]
            { 
                GetString(Resource.String.menu_item_play),
                GetString(Resource.String.menu_item_scores),
                GetString(Resource.String.menu_item_settings),
                GetString(Resource.String.menu_item_help)
            };

        ArrayAdapter<string> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.MenuItem, items);
        menuList.Adapter = adapt;
    }
}
```

I tried

This

```
            menuList.Click +=new EventHandler(menuList_Click);

   void menuList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // stuff here
        }
```

I tried

```
menuList.Click += (sender, e) => { };
```

They all just hang and say something like

> This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from
>   the current function.

No other errors are displayed.

It dies right on the creation of the click event. I got nothing in the actual click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want menuList.ItemClick instead of Click.

Comment: @pobst- did not even see that as a choice. Ya I probably should be using that. Is Click  some event choice that shows up in intellisense but is actually not supported? Since it's not like I clicked on it and then it crashed. The whole view does not load up. As it dies on that line. It seems to load up now. I also tried to do it the other way with  menuList.SetOnClickListener that takes in a View.IOnClickListener. It also failed and there is no SetOnClickItemListener that way.

Comment: Click is on the base View class that ListView subclasses.  It may fire when the ListView itself is clicked (that is, click on a part that doesn't have an item).  Or it may just be overridden and not actually do anything.

Comment: - Still don't understand why it would crash if there is no logic in the actual event.

Comment: Mono for Android may be doing something wrong, but the actual problem is that subscribing to the AdapterView.Click event is tantamount to calling AdapterView.setOnClickListener(), and calling setOnClickListener() results in a RuntimeException: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/AdapterView.java;h=8fcc2e87a966b70fc24b17c16da994538832aff6;hb=HEAD#l748